# QuickSort Python Implementation. Order of return is incorrect

Tags: python, quicksort

I am implementing the following QuickSort without keeping track of start and end indexes + using recursion. My print statements are correct on how it is being ordered, but when the recursive functions return it gets swapped back?

```
def sortArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:

  
    # quick sort implementation
    if (len(nums) <= 1):
        return None
    
    pivot = nums[-1]
    pointer = 0
    iter_pointer = 0

    while iter_pointer < len(nums) - 1 :                
        if (nums[iter_pointer] <= pivot):
            temp = nums[iter_pointer]
            nums[iter_pointer] = nums[pointer]
            nums[pointer] = temp
            pointer += 1
        
        iter_pointer += 1
    
    #put pivot in middle
    nums[-1] = nums[pointer]
    nums[pointer] = pivot

    self.sortArray(nums[:pointer])
    self.sortArray(nums[pointer + 1:])

    return nums
```

Comment: What `print` statements?

Comment: As an aside, you are defeating the purpose of doing in-place partitioning when you make copies of the halves of the list to pass to the recursive calls.

Comment: Deleted them for cleanliness. Print statements immediately after the 'pivot in the middle' outputs the correct left and right order throughout the recursion, but the final returns does not reflect that. I suspect some issue with indexes and the recursion messing it up

Comment: That's a good point. I have a index "start" and "end" version that works fine, but wanted to implement one without those even if its not the most effective.

Comment: Your recursive calls are sorting *brand-new lists*, with no connection to the list originally passed in.  Nothing that they do has any lasting effect.  Passing explicit start/end indexes is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function with the left and right parts or the pivot value, you're implicitly creating new lists so whatever sorting happens in them does not update your original nums list.

`nums[:pointer]`  produces a new list, it is not a slice of the original

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the issue is fundamentally that you're sorting copies of the sublists without reassigning them. This isn't very efficient, but to make it work the way you have it, you also need to make sure to change the return statement at the beginning, or alternatively use one return statement and put the rest of the logic under the condition. Here's a full working example:

```
class Sort(object):
    def sortArray(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        if nums:
            pivot = nums[-1]
            pointer = 0
            iter_pointer = 0

            while iter_pointer < len(nums) - 1:
                if nums[iter_pointer] <= pivot:
                    temp = nums[iter_pointer]
                    nums[iter_pointer] = nums[pointer]
                    nums[pointer] = temp
                    pointer += 1
                iter_pointer += 1

            nums[-1] = nums[pointer]
            nums[pointer] = pivot

            # Assign recursive output
            nums[:pointer] = self.sortArray(nums[:pointer])
            nums[pointer + 1 :] = self.sortArray(nums[pointer + 1 :])

        return nums
```

I ran it on a handful of hand-tailored tests and random tests:

```
input -> output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 1] -> [1, 2, 3]
[5, 7, 3] -> [3, 5, 7]
[5, 7, 3, 1, 9] -> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[27, 67, 11, 77, 19, 71, 17, 72, 13, 77] -> [11, 13, 17, 19, 27, 67, 71, 72, 77, 77]
[79, 39, 47, 71, 91, 81, 72, 68, 48, 90] -> [39, 47, 48, 68, 71, 72, 79, 81, 90, 91]
[68, 3, 21, 72, 74, 47, 22, 91, 94, 19] -> [3, 19, 21, 22, 47, 68, 72, 74, 91, 94]
[7, 25, 80, 59, 71, 26, 52, 51, 89, 99] -> [7, 25, 26, 51, 52, 59, 71, 80, 89, 99]
[33, 95, 2, 20, 20, 38, 48, 64, 62, 78] -> [2, 20, 20, 33, 38, 48, 62, 64, 78, 95]
[61, 2, 38, 71, 68, 10, 32, 79, 50, 0] -> [0, 2, 10, 32, 38, 50, 61, 68, 71, 79]
```